# How to have 2 filters in 1 image opencv

Tags: python, opencv

How to have a single of output image with 2 filters including half of greyscale and half of sobel

Comment: Do you mean to have one filter on left half of the image and the other on the right?

Comment: Half a filter plus half a filter should be one filter shouldn't it?

Comment: @UdayrajDeshmukh Yes,that is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Just assign left and right halves separately to the image. The following pseudocode will help you understand how to do it.

```
out1 = filter1(img); 

out2 = filter2(img);

l = img.width; # for horizontal effect, use img.height
img[0:l/2] = out1[0:l/2];

img[l/2:l] = out2[l/2:l];
```